Macro for notepad++ - nested opening {} with indentation
I'm trying to create a macro to quickly enter two matching braces {} with an empty line in between that has the deeper indentation.
My current macro performs this sequence:

{
Enter
Enter
}
↑
Tab

This works fine, and returns the expected brace-pair and indentation between them:
{

}

But with nested brackets, the closing } has no indentation:
{
    {

} <--
}

How to overcome this?

You could duplicate the indent that was already made to two new lines, using the "duplicate selection" command, usually mapped to Ctrl+D, but check your mapped key in Settings > Shortcut Mapper:

The key sequence would be:

End to place the caret at the end of the current line
{
Ctrl+D to copy the current line (together with the brace)
↓ to move caret to the end of the copied line
Shift+Home to select the text on the copied line
Del to remove that text (at least the brace)
Ctr+D to duplicate this empty line
↓
}
Up
Tab

This will also work as expected when there is already text on the current line.
